# why nautilus will open automatically when kde loads?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, kubuntu, kde

Recentlly every time that laptop turns on and  kde loads, nautilus will opened automatically.
**why ?**

I installed kde on ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Maybe ?**

As default the KDE is trying to restore the previous session. KDE System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Session management.

Try with the "Start with an empty session".

[image]

In other words, even though you close Nautilus before ending your KDE session. KDE is currently incapable of keeping track of this correctly and as such KDE will try to restore your Nautilus session even though it was closed before you ended your previous KDE session. This is a bug that will most likely not get fixed because of its low priority. So at present this is the only way to stop KDE from launching Nautilus at login.

Comment: It worked for me with KDE 4.10.1 ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On KDE System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Session management, write "nautilus" on the field "Applications to be excluded from sessions:". It is better than selecting "Start with an empty session" because you don't lose the functionality of having you previous session restored.

Answer (score 0):

Start Session Management
Change to Start with an empty session
exit
log off
Login again
Nautilus will be off
Now go back to Session Management
Select Restore previous session
Exit
Log off
Log on
Nautilus does not start as you wanted and the "On login" setting is the way it was when you started.