# KDE opens recent session applications

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde4, kde-apps

When I restart KDE, it launches all the applications I opened after restart. How to disable this feature?

Comment: Do you mean: "When I restart KDE, it launches all the applications I opened before the restart." - If yes: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117565/why-nautilus-will-open-automatically-when-kde-loads

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown (in the System Administration section) -> Session Management. Change the On Login option at the bottom to *Start with an empty session*, and then click *Apply*.