# How to prevent Nautilus from starting in KDE?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, kde

I have KDE installed in Ubuntu (not Kubuntu) and the Nautilus starts with it.

But it should start only in GNOME or Unity:

```
$ grep OnlyShowIn /etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop 
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

Uninstalling Nautilus or saving the KDE session is not an option. It should not start at all.

Comment: Replace the nautilus executable with a file that has one line `#!/bin/sh`. Then it will "not start at all".

Comment: I have multiple DEs and it will break GNOME and Unity. Thus not an option also, but thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: This was a sarcastic comment. Your question is ambiguous and I don't understand how and why Nautilus starts and what exactly you want to prevent.

Comment: Do you have both KDE and Unity installed?

Comment: I had a simmilar problem, for which I found the solution described http://askubuntu.com/questions/117565/why-nautilus-will-open-automatically-when-kde-loads?rq=1 worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was some bug. Nautilus no longer starts after downgrading from -proposed repository.

Comment: Since the bug appears to be regression introduced by the new packages currently being tested in `-proposed`, I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). One benefit of doing so is to decrease the likelihood that the bug will be released into `-security` and/or `-updates` and come back in an update (for you, and/or other users). You can look at `/var/log/dpkg.log`, `/var/log/apt/history.log`, and/or `/var/log/apt/term.log` to see what packages were upgraded/downgraded to/from `-proposed`, to help narrow down *what package* is producing the problem.

Comment: Once you think you know what package it's probably in, you can report it against that package--it can be corrected later. But it's best to report it against the right package initially if possible, in part because Apport will include different data automatically depending on what package you say has the bug. I'm not sure what specific package would be causing this, and there are people much more knowledgeable about KDE than I am. But if you want help tracking this down, I'd be pleased to help; *please feel free to ping me in chat*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the `-proposed` again in VM. Unfortunately, I have `/var/log` in tmpfs and the machine was switched off.