# After installing kde-full package at start-up nautilus automatically opens my home folder

Tags: nautilus, kde

I have installed the `kde-full` package on Ubuntu 12.04 in order to switch to the KDE plasma workspace as well as install the other applications. It works well with just one problem that I can't understand.

Whenever I start a new session nautilus opens up my home folder and I have to manually close it.

It's pretty annoying, but I don't want to uninstall nautilus just to stop this behavior.

I have already looked into my `~/.bashrc` and I haven't seen any additions which would make nautilus do this.

I've found the answer in a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117565/why-nautilus-will-open-automatically-when-kde-loads?rq=1), I verified it and it works for me, so I will close this question.

Comment: Just be clear, when using KDE plasma, you are having Nautilus (not Dolphin) pop up?

Comment: Yes, Nautilus the GNOME file explorer and it pops up of it's own volition just once at every new session, beyond that Nautilus works fine.

Comment: Have you checked if Nautilus is set to start when you log in using Startup Applications?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and it does not appear to be selected.